# Embedded youtube video restarts on resize

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, youtube, resize

I have a Youtube video embedded on my site, and when the iframe that it is embedded in gets resized, the Youtube video restarts. Is this the expected behaviour? Is there any way around it? I have been trying to get the Youtube JS API working to no success, so I would prefer to not use it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

How about you get the minute/second the video is at the moment of the resize so you reload it but with an auto starts on the same minute/second?

For example if you add this at the end of a youtube url it starts at minute 1 and 8 seconds:

`#t=1m08s`

Comment: Yeah, that is what I was trying. I don't know how to do it without the JSApi....Any idea?

Comment: Maybe you could use the php time function, save the starting time when you open/click the non resized video and then when you "zoom" it grab another time and compare it with the last one. Then pass the result as variables via POST/GET to the url thingy. Seems a bit of a pain but it should work!

Comment: Yup. That is about the only option. It assumes that people cannot pause/move through the video - but as of right now, its the only option. Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to give me a "tick/positive" so if anyone has the same issue knows it works! and no problem, glad it helped!